# Making a program that sends data to USB port

Tags: usb, c, communication, java

I want to create a program that is able to communicate to the USB port on my laptop. From this program I want to send data to the USB port constantly. Basically something like a hyperterminal, but more graphical. Like buttons, graphs etc. (GUI)

I never created programs, so don't know where to start.
I have experience with Eclipse, C-language and Java, if this is important.
What program should be better (and maybe easy to use) for my purpose?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PC programming.

Comment: Consider using a FTDI USB <-> Serial converter, then your task will be simplified to sending data over serial protocol.

Comment: No point sending data to the USB port unless there is something connected. What do you want to communicate with?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is maybe a pure "software" problem.

If you need send data to USB port, you need do something in two levels.

Driver level: If your device is a commercial one, and if the vendor support you one driver, you can use it. But if not, you may need make it by yourself, or use the generic one. In Windows, there are **kernel level** and **user level**, both can be developed under [WDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Kit). And you can also use the generic one: http://www.libusb.org/, it can be used both on Windows and Linux, and easy to use.

Application level: You can develop your applications using your favorite language/IDE to communicate with your USB device through your USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at http://www.libusb.org/ 
It works with C Language on a variety of different OS. It does NOT help you to make a GUI.